# Count 2- and 3-word strings frequency in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hello smart human beings out there

I have this setup in my Excel

[image]

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve here is automatically grab every single string from column A (and paste to column H) and return the frequency in column I. The script is below

```
Sub WordCountTester()
    Dim d As Object, k, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws.ListObjects("Table3")
        If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
            .DataBodyRange.Delete
        End If
    End With
    Set d = WordCounts(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row), _
                       ws.Range("F2:F" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row))
    'list words and frequencies
    For Each k In d.keys
        ws.Range("H2").Resize(1, 2).Offset(i, 0).Value = Array(k, d(k))
        i = i + 1
    Next k
End Sub

'rngTexts = range with text to be word-counted, defined in set d= above
'rngExclude = 'range with words to exclude from count, defined in set d= above
Public Function WordCounts(rngTexts As Range, rngExclude As Range) As Object 'dictionary
    Dim words, c As Range, dict As Object, regexp As Object, w, wd As String, m
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    Set regexp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'see link below for reference
    With regexp
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .ignorecase = True
        .Pattern = "[\dA-Z-]{3,}" 'at least 3 characters
     End With
     'loop over input range
     For Each c In rngTexts.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            Set words = regexp.Execute(LCase(c.Value))
            'loop over matches
            For Each w In words
                wd = w.Value 'the text of the match
                If Len(wd) > 1 Then  'EDIT: ignore single characters
                   'increment count if the word is not found in the "excluded" range
                    If IsError(Application.Match(wd, rngExclude, 0)) Then
                        dict(wd) = dict(wd) + 1
                    End If
                End If '>1 char
            Next w
        End If
            Next c
     Set WordCounts = dict
End Function
```

However, it currently count the string with 1 word only. I want to count strings with 2 and 3 words (and I will consider drive-by as 2 words). Can someone please tell me where in this code I have to fix to achieve that? I still want to keep column F there because there can be 2- or 3- word strings that I want to exclude. Thanks!

Comment: What do you understand by "every string"? Do you want meaning "every word", in fact? Or the value of each cell in A:A, even if contains more words? If so, why pasting it in another column?

Comment: What does "count strings with 2 and 3 words" means? Your code correctly counts **words having >= 3 digits**. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Hello, so per my example, if I want the list of all 2-word strings, column H should return: this is, is not, not casey, casey mcquiston's, ....

Does it make sense?

Comment: What does "2-word strings" means? Please, write one, two examples... Did you design the above code, or you took it from the internet and have different expectations than the code returns?

Comment: I took a similar code on the Internet and fix some pieces to fit what I need in the past. But now the requirement is to count the frequency of the 2-word strings, not single-word string anymore. So in the past column H returns: this, is, not, casey, mcquiston's, etc. then column I returns the count of each instance. Now I want column H to return: this is, is not, not casey, casey mcquiston's, etc. instead and column I still returns the count of each instance

Comment: You could `Split` on spaces and then iterate through and grab (0) and (1), (1) and (2), ... Though that doesn't help you with hyphenates, which I expect will make this hellishly complex as you start to add a third word or more exceptions.

Comment: I actually figured this out. I changed .Pattern = "[\dA-Z-]{3,}" to .Pattern = "[\dA-Z-]+\s[\dA-Z-]+"

Comment: Do you only need pairs of words 1-2, 3-4, 5-6 and not also 2-3, 4-5, 6-7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you changed your mind and consider that **also** two words pairs 2-3, 4-5, 6-7 and so on are necessary, please test the next solution:

```
Private Sub WordPairsCountTester()
    Dim d As Object, k, i As Long, ws As Worksheet, arrFin
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    'Attention, please! The last parameter of the called function means How Many Consecutive Words to be counted
    Set d = WordPairCountsSp(ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.cells(rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row), _
                                        ws.Range("F2:F" & ws.cells(rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).row), 3)
                                        
    arrFin = Application.Transpose(Array(d.Keys, d.items))    'place the dictionary in an array
    'clear contents of the columns where a previous result was returned, if any...:
    ws.Range("H2:I" & ws.Range("H" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row).ClearContents
    ws.Range("H2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 2).Value = arrFin  'drop the array content at once
End Sub

Private Function WordPairCountsSp(rngTexts As Range, rngExclude As Range, nrNeigh As Long) As Object
      Dim dict As Object, arr, arrCell, i As Long, pairWd As String, j As Long, k As Long
      arr = rngTexts.Value         'place the range in an array for faster iteration
      Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For i = 1 To UBound(arr)     'iterate between the array elements
            arrCell = Split(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(arr(i, 1), ",", ""), ".", ""), "?", ""), "!", "")) 'split the string by default delimiter (space)
            If UBound(arrCell) + 1 >= nrNeigh Then
                For j = 0 To UBound(arrCell) - nrNeigh + 1     'iterate between the array elements
                    pairWd = arrCell(j)
                    For k = 1 To nrNeigh - 1
                        pairWd = pairWd & " " & arrCell(j + k) 'create a string from nrNeigh neighbour words
                    Next k
                    If IsError(Application.match(pairWd, rngExclude, 0)) Then
                            dict(pairWd) = dict(pairWd) + 1  'place the unique pairs as keys and add occurrences as items
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
      Next i
      Set WordPairCountsSp = dict  'return the above created dictionary
End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate the help! I will let you know if I have any issue with this code

Comment: Hi, your script works flawlessly! How do I make this "dynamic" though, meaning how can I make this look at 3, 4, 5, etc. neighbour words (and even 1 word as well), not just 2.? To elaborate: if my string is "Thank you so much for your help", your script returns:
thank you
you so
so much
....

But if I want 3 neighbor words, it should return:
thank you so
you so much
so much for
much for your
...

Comment: To clarify on the question above, I don't need the script to be "dynamic" per se. I just need to know what I need to modify in order to get the x neighbor words

Comment: @Long N I must tell you that this is a different question and we here do not proceed in this way. Does the above code answer your question **as it was formulated**? Otherwise, it may become a never ending story. Anyhow, I am somewhere without my laptop and I will not be at home until Sunday. Please, post another question and tag me here if somebody else will not solve it. If I will have access to a computer I will try helping even earlier. I will also like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**.

Comment: Alright I accepted your answer although I was asking how to count the 3-word string in the beginning but maybe I wasn't too clear.  Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @@Long N Yes, you asked, indeed. In a way we couldn't understand what you want, but it is so easy to adapt the code to process such 3 neighbor words. I will do it even copying on mobile phone. But I was referring to the request of a general algorithm able to return in case of **any "X" neighbor words**. I have something in mind, anyhow...

Comment: @Long N About the global algorithm, how to proceed in case the processed cells has less words than the specified needed number? Should it skip the cell? I am asking that to make the algorithm to not return an error in such a case...

Comment: @Long N If you need the version using a global algorithm and asked such a question, please tag me here with a link to it. Like I said, I have something in my mind...

Comment: I super appreciate your helps here. So to answer your multiple questions
.  But I was referring to the request of a general algorithm able to return in case of any "X" neighbor words.  - Yes this would be nice BUT I don't think you need to spend much time on this. I think maximum is 5 since the more words we want to combine, the higher chance the frequency will only be 1 anyway
. About the global algorithm, how to proceed in case the processed cells has less words than the specified needed number? Yes, the cell can be skipped.
. I'm not familiar with private vs global though :(

Comment: For now I will just create 2 separate buttons 1 for pair of 2 and 1 for pair of 3 :)

Comment: Also, in my old code, I don't want to count punctuation and special characters (so for "I love you so much" and "I love, you so much", "I love you" will be counted as 2). I'm not sure how hard is it to fix it here though. I guess I can replace all of those as "" in my raw data but not sure if it's possible that this code can do this for the user

Comment: @Long N I have a laptop available and I will adapt the code in order to work for any number of words (a new parameter in the called function) and preliminarily replace the punctuation characters (".", ",", "?", "!").

Comment: @Long N Please, test the updated solution and send some feedback. Supposing that it should be on your taste, we here also vote the code up... :)